# SQL query to extract a number and its decimal variations

Tags: sql, netezza

I have column with all kinds of numbers, I am specifically trying to extract numbers that have either

```
555
```

or

```
555.xx
```

or

```
555.x
```

The output should look like this

```
555
555.1
555.5
555.9
555.58
555.22
.
.
```

IE I need an sql query that will return the rows that have just the number 555 with any decimal fraction from my column of arbitrary numbers.

Comment: What is the type of the column?  Can you post some sample data and what you would like returned?

Comment: @AbeMiessler, not sure how to check what type of column I am dealing with but I updated how I want the output to look.

Comment: I don't see any updates.  Google `how to check SQL Server column type` - this is required information if you want the right answer.

Comment: @AbeMiessler its a select CHARACTER VARYING(10) type of column

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Netezza (IBM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `LIKE` statement

```
WHERE Col LIKE '555.%'
OR Col = '555'
```

Answer (score 1):

As a fast approach I would do

```
CAST((ValueOfTable * 100.00) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
```

> my table name is Diagnosis and the column name is code, where should I
>   add the table name and column name in this code ?

In your situation:

```
SELECT
CAST((code * 100.00) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) 
FROM Diagnosis ;
```

I'm expecting this to be an integer. You can find out executing:

```
\d Diagnosis ;
```

one of the output lines should look similar to

```
 (...)
 code                       | integer                     | 
 (...)
```

Comment: my table name is Diagnosis and the column name is code, where should I add the table name and column name in this code ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column contains numbers (not as string/varchar), search for "number>=555 and number<556". This would give you 555, 555.01... etc.

Comment: @Micheal, the column I am dealing with contains all types of characters and number except special characters so column type is character.

Answer (score 1):

If the CODE column is a varchar (which I understand it to be from your comments, but you might want clarify that in the question body itself), and can/does contain values that are not numbers, then you have to be very careful about using functions which only accept a number.

With this sample data, you can see that having one value that can't be cast to a number will cause the whole query to error out.

```
select * from diagnosis order by code;
   CODE
-----------
 555
 555.0
 555.43
 555.99
 Not a Num
(5 rows)

select code + 1 from diagnosis;
ERROR:  pg_atoi: error in "Not a Num": can't parse "Not a Num"
```

The usual solution to this is to either match the column value via regular expression, or use a function to test whether or now the value in each row is a number.

Here are two solutions, each of which depends on a function that is provided with Netezza, but not necessarily installed by default.  Your administrator can install these for you.

The first uses the regexp_instr from the SQL Extension Toolkit. Here you use a regular expression to match the values you want without having to do an actual CAST (implicit or explicit) to a numeric.

```
SELECT code FROM diagnosis
WHERE regexp_instr(code, '^555(\.\d+)?$') > 0;

  CODE
--------
 555
 555.0
 555.43
 555.99
(4 rows)
```

The second solution, which is a bit more involved, uses the isnumeric() UDF provided as part of the Netezza InDatabase Analytics package (in the /nz/extensions/nz/nzlua/examples directory when installed), to test whether the CODE column is a numeric before casting CODE as a numeric.

```
SELECT code
FROM (
      SELECT code
      FROM diagnosis
      WHERE isnumber(code)
   )
   foo
WHERE floor(code::NUMERIC(38,2)) = 555;

  CODE
--------
 555
 555.0
 555.43
 555.99
(4 rows)
```

Both of these functions are *included* with Netezza, but both require installation by your administrator before you can use them. In each case this is a simple task for the administrator, although they may not be aware of their availability.

Comment: i tried this and got an error ` ERROR: Function 'ISNUMBER(VARCHAR)' does not exsist, Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types. You may need to add explicit typecasts `

Comment: Both of these functions need to be explicitly made available to you by your administrator. Both are made available with the system, but have to be installed/configured